# WPF media element gets blank and VLC and WMP goes in non responding mode

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc, mediaelement, wmp

I have C# windows application in which one can play videos. I have used three options i.e WPF mediaelement, Windows media player activex component and vlc activex component. In my application. In this I plays video using one of the component at a time. And for that I use two instances of that particular component i.e. first video will play in first instance, then second video will play in second instance, then third will play in first and fourth will in second like this it will go on. the play duration is min 5 secs to some hrs. Now,

1. When I use WPF media element after some hours the form gets blank and application hangs (I have log4net to log and whenever it gets blank it stops logging) but in task manager instaed  of showing not responding it shows running. Also, sometimes it takes lots of memeory.
2. When I use WMP or VLC activex com object after some hrs appliaction goes in non responding mode and task manager shows it correctly. In this there is no memory problem.

After seeing the above results I strated disposing the objects after its turn gets over. So for each video there is a new instance of the above mentioned components. But still I am getting same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar project to yours where I'm using VLC activex. I experienced the same problems you are describing. To solve this issue, I've added the VLC pluging in a a GroupBox and disabled the GroupBox by setting the Enabled property to false. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying. By adding plugins in groupbox , how are you using them. I am just creating the object of VLC activex and then called the play method after setting some propertis like size, url, position. Can you please tell how you are using those plugins and what extra things I will have to do?